# CSS não funciona no IOS

Tags: css, ios, iphone

Meu site fica todo bugado no IOS, é por que o css não carrega? Como eu poderia contornar o problema? Existe algum console de IOS, igual do Chrome e Firefox, pra ajeitar o site? no Android ele funciona normal.

Comment: Tem como descrever melhor o "bugado"? :)

Comment: Desculpa, Renan, mas só achei essa palavra pra descrever rs. No caso não funciona parece, o CSS, o site fica todo desajeitado, com um estilo indesejável, má aparência, etc...

Comment: Como está a tag de chamada do CSS? É por tag `<style>` ou `<link>`? Existe uma aplicação chamada iTools onde é possível ver os logs do iOS, talvez você encontre algo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voce teria que testar de um OSX para ver, mas se o CSS fica zoado, provavelmente e o padrao, voce pode resetar os valores padroes de CSS do OSX

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
```

ve se funciona

Comment: Sabe de algum emulador de OS X, Rafael?

Comment: Emulador nao cara, mas se voce fizer o upload para o servidor e me passar o link, posso testar aqui. ou tambem pode emular uma maquina virtual e instalar o OSX